# Quartz Scheduler fails if I change system timezone

Tags: quartz.net, misfire-instruction

We have a scheduler that got triggered at 12 AM everyday. It work perfectly until I do not change timezone such that it skips next subsequent calls.

Example, Current time and Date is 4 PM of 10th February, I change timezone such that new time is 12:30 AM of 11th February.

Result:

No trigger happens after that.

Expected:

Skipping Trigger on 12:00 AM on 11th February is acceptable but it should execute all subsequent schedules at 12 AM every day.

I have not included any misfire instruction. Please help me.